# configure glassfish embedded server with logback logging

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, logback

Is there any way to configure Glassfish embedded server for testing with third party logging frameworks - particularly Logback (or) LOG4j.
Note: Glassfish embedded server is used for unit testing our EJB Beans.

Comment: Glassfish uses java.util.logging which you can forward to slf4j using the [jul-to-slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html#jul-to-slf4j) bridge which in turn will be picked up by Logback. Add all the jars to the classpath, add a logback.xml and you should get it working.